# How do I set my DNS Server setting in Windows, if I have no network adapter

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10, dns, network-adapter

So I only have one Network Adapter "Wifi" where I have set DNS server to 127.0.0.1.

But sometime there is no Wifi Connection, and Windows (at least Chrome/Firefox) stop using this configured DNS server.

Is it possible to make Windows to use my specified DNS Server if there is no network connection?

I would prefer if I can set a DNS server setting somewhere else globally so I am not dependent upon network adapters.

Comment: What is the point of having a DNS server if you do not have a connection to the internet. Also, the IP address of 127.0.0.1 is a loopback IP meaning your computer is using itself as a DNS server.

Comment: @zandermar18 Yes. I have a DNS server hosted locally. It has entries like `127.0.0.1 *.win`, which helps in having developing projects using custom hostnames. `hosts` file alone doesn't support wildcard records.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since you require the use of custom hostnames located on a local DNS server the best thing to do would be to create a virtual network adapter. This should trick Windows into thinking it is connected to the internet when it is not, and you should be able to use your local DNS to do your project development.

Comment: How do I create "virtual network adapter"?